# Simplify the following differential equation by variable scaling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, biology

We have: $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{a}{x+b}, a>0,b>0$.

We make substitutes: $x\to\alpha h, t\to\beta \tau$.

Then the differential equation will be:
$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{a}{x+b}$, We divide by $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ and then we have: $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\frac{a}{x+b}$.

We choose the constants a and b as follows: $a=\alpha $ and $\beta=b$ and we get $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{\frac{h}{b}+1}$. Now we will note $\frac{1}{b}=\theta$ and we will have $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{\theta h +1}$.

To this problem I was asked to make both parameters disappear, which seems impossible to me.

Is there a variant?
Please a hint!

Thank you !

Comment: Try the change $z = \frac{x+b}{\sqrt{a}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if this is what you want but if you are allowed to use shifts doing the change of variables

$$y=x+b, s=at$$

would transform

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{a}{x+b} \quad\text{to}\quad \dfrac{dy}{ds}=\dfrac{1}{y}.$$